# How can you detect if ANY sounds are currently playing in soundJS?

Tags: audio, createjs, soundjs

How can you detect if any sounds are playing in soundJS?

I have lots of sounds firing on and off sometimes legitimately over the top of each other. I need a way to find out if any sounds are playing at any given time 
ie. something like

createjs.Sound.isPlaying()

or

createjs.Sound.status()

Answer (score 2):

Nothing exists like this in SoundJS currently.

You can look it up yourself, but it involves digging into private members, which is **not recommended**, and could break content down the road. Here is a quick sample:

```
function countActiveSounds() { 
    var s = createjs.Sound.activePlugin, 
        count = 0; 
    for (var n in s._soundInstances) { 
        var inst = s._soundInstances[n];
        for (var i=0, l=inst.length; i<l; i++) {
            var p = inst[i];
            if (p.playState == "playSucceeded") { count++; }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

This involves reading the private `_soundInstances` hash, and checking if the sound state is "playSucceeded". Once it is complete, the state will changed to "playFinished".

Again, use this with caution :)

It might make sense to log a feature request to the [SoundJS GitHub](http://github.com/CreateJS/SoundJS/issues).

Comment: Thanks Lanny, I made a workaround by adding 1 to a variable any sound that starts and removing from the total any sound that stops. If the total is more than 0 then in theory no sounds are currently playing. This is susceptible to getting out of sync but seems to be working for now.